# Numerically checking if expression is 0

Tags: numerics

I ended up with the example below after some debugging. An expression at the end,  `Norm[A . X1 + X1 . A - B]` is zero. However,

- using `N` gives around `0 + 0.002 i`, fails approximate numerical equality testing
- using `N[...,100]` gives `Indeterminate`

Is there a more robust way of testing expressions for zero numerically?

```
(* Solve Lyapunov equation A,B *)
A = {{10, 17}, {17, 29}};
B = {{26, 2}, {2, 4}};

normalize[vec_] := vec/Norm[vec];
evecs[mat_] := Transpose[normalize /@ Eigenvectors[mat]];

U = evecs[A];

s = Eigenvalues[A];
sdiv = 1/Outer[Plus, s, s];
Y = (U\[Transpose] . B . U)*sdiv;
X1 = U . Y . Transpose[U];
X2 = LyapunovSolve[A, B];
Print["X1 == X2 ", Reduce[X1 == X2] ];   (* True *) 
Print["error X2 ", N@Norm[A . X2 + X2 . A - B]];  (* 0 *)

Print["error X1 ", N@Norm[A . X1 + X1 . A - B]]; (* 0 + 0.002 i *)
Print["error X1 ", N[Norm[A . X1 + X1 . A - B], 100]]; (* Indeterminate *)
```

Comment: Note that `Norm[N[A.X1+X1.A-B]]` is very small, perhaps you can use that? Directly calculating the matrix-`Norm` of a matrix with exact entries (which calculates singular values and so on in exact arithmetic) perhaps leads to trouble.

Comment: I was looking for something I could use in my unit tests. I suspect the underlying problem is intractable in full generality, but wondering if there's an automatic solution which works better than N

Comment: Have you looked at `PossibleZeroQ[]` already?

Comment: Check out the last example with this: `Simplify@Norm[A . X1 + X1 . A - B]`. `Norm[]` seems to do a no-no. Then try this: `Norm[A . N[X1, 100] + X1 . A - B]`. Or this: `Norm[A . Simplify[X1] + Simplify[X1] . A - B]`. Or `RootReduce[X1]` to limit the kind of simplification.

Comment: Possibly simpler: Use `Together[X1]` instead of `X1`.  There's some algebra that needs to be done before numericizing, it seems.

Comment: That works, seems more generally I could just add something like below in my tests `Simplify[X1, TimeConstraint -> {.01, .01}]`

Answer (score 1):

This is a convenient form in which to apply `PossibleZeroQ`. It returns `True` if the first argument is a matrix all of whose elements pass the `PossibleZeroQ` test.

```
MatrixQ[A . ExpandAll[X1] + ExpandAll[X1] . A - B, PossibleZeroQ]
(* True  *)
```

`PossibleZeroQ`, which was [suggested by @J.M. in a comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/270759/numerically-checking-if-expression-is-0#comment675864_270759), uses both symbolic and numeric methods to test for zero. As the docs for `PossibleZeroQ` mention:

> The general problem of determining whether an expression has value zero is undecidable; `PossibleZeroQ` provides a quick but not always accurate test.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar need lately and came up with this:

```
NEqual[x1_,x2_,opts___?OptionQ]:=Module[{samethreshold},
    samethreshold=Evaluate[SameThreshold/.Flatten[{opts,Options[NEqual]}]];
    If[
        Dimensions[x1,AllowedHeads->"ListLike"]==Dimensions[x2,AllowedHeads->"ListLike"],
        Return[If[Norm[x1-x2]<samethreshold,True,False,False]],
        Message[NEqual::nedd];
        Return[False]
    ];
];

Options[NEqual]={SameThreshold->10^-8};

NEqual::nedd="Arguments of NEqual have different dimensions.";
```

Of course, since your expression is `0 + 0.002 i` it gives `False`:

```
NEqual[N@Norm[A . X1 + X1 . A - B], 0]
(* False *)
```

but I just thought I'd throw it out there in case anyone has suggestions for improvement.